# How to move a point along a plane?

Tags: vectors

So lets say Point P $(-3, -5, -1)$ is on a Plane $2x+2y-z=-15$. And lets say I want to move this point $3$ units left or $3$ units right along the plane, how can I do that?

I feel like doing this doesn't make sense:

$(-3 + 3, -5 + 3, -1 + 3)$

Like I don't want to move the point away from the plane, I want the point still be on the plane after the point moves.

Comment: What do you mean by left and right, in this context? For example, if you want to keep the $z$-component constant, you could assume a parametric line at $z=-1$ and then you have
$$
2x + 2y - (-1) = -15
\qquad
\Rightarrow
\qquad
2\frac{dx}{dt} + 2 \frac{dy}{dt} = 0
$$
Therefore, the change you make in the $x$-coordinate has to be $-1$ times the change in the $y$-coordinate. So if you start at $(-3,-5,-1)$, you could move to
$$
(-3+3, -5-3,-1)
$$
You can check that this point is still in the plane.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Got a hint from the diagram?

> All you need to do is find an equation of a circle with radius 3 lying on the plane $2x+2y-z=-15$ with the point $(-3,-5,-1)$ as the center and then all the points lying on the circle is the point 3 units away from $(-3,-5,-1)$.

Finding the locus of points 3 units away from Point P...

- The normal vector of the plane is $2\widehat i+2\widehat j-\widehat k$
- Find another point on the plane, so for simplicity substitute $x \text{ and } y =0$, we get $z=-15$. Another point on the plane is $(0,0,-15)$.
- Vector between P and $(0,0,-15)$ is $3\widehat i +5\widehat i -14\widehat k$
- Cross product between the normal vector ($2\widehat i+2\widehat j-\widehat k$) and $3\widehat i +5\widehat i -14\widehat k$ is $-23\widehat i -25\widehat j +4\widehat k$ whose direction ratios parallel to this will lie on the plane.

So a line passing through the point P is
$$\frac{x+3}{-23}=\frac{y+5}{-25}=\frac{z+1}{4}$$

Likewise, find another point on the plane & find the equation of the line passing through the Point P (probably this time you substitute $x \text{ and } z =0$). And using the equations of lines obtained, find the equation of the circle passing through them.

Comment: Hi Mr Rash, I attempted to do it already but my working seems off, can you provide more guidance? Many thanks again!

Comment: @Negrawh ok, I will edit the post

Comment: The circle has the equation of $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2$ but now we have a point with $x$, $y$ and $z$. If I were to extend the circle equation to include $(z-b)^2$, it becomes a sphere?

Comment: @Negrawh Edited with more clues. Can you continue from here? Also, one important thing you are missing out. Imagine, if you know three points of a circle, you can find a circle that lies on fixed plane!

Comment: But in this case, you already know the centre of the circle. So all you need to know is only two other points on the circle and fit it in the equation. Done!

Comment: and also don't call me mister lol. I'm only a high school kid

Comment: Sorry rash, but how do you know that the cross product between the normal vector ($2\widehat i+2\widehat j-\widehat k$) and $3\widehat i +5\widehat i -14\widehat k$ will give a vector that lie on the plane?

Comment: Hi rash thanks for the edit again,  I am still unsure how to use the equations of lines obtained to find the equation of the circle passing through them. How can I mathematically represent this? Sorry I am very slow

Comment: @Negrawh Reminder, vectors is all about imagination. Reverse imagine this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Cross_product_animation.gif

Comment: and you will know why cross product gives a line on the plane